# How can I specify the location of child components in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Consider a Vue component `my-wrapper`

```
<template>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="outer">
      <!-- render children here? -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And it is intended to be used like so:

```
<template>
  <my-wrapper>
    <h1>Cards</h1>
    <card :data="card1"/>
    <card :data="card2"/>
  </my-wrapper>
</template>
```

How can I specify the location of child components in the `my-wrapper` component?

---

*Bonus* Is it also possible to pass in named child components and place them at various locations in the Vue.js template? Eg something like this? (Which obviously doesn't work):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="left">
      <place-child ref-name="left"></place-child>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <place-child ref-name="left"></place-child>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Example usage of `my-wrapper`:

```
<template>
  <my-wrapper>
    <card ref="left" :data="card1"/>
    <card ref="right" :data="card2"/>
  </my-wrapper>
</template>
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Content Distribution https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Answer (score 2):

Vue supports this using [content distribution with slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots). You can use the `<slot>` element to mark slots within your template where children are to be rendered. You can also use [named slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Named-Slots) to have multiple different targets within your template.

Using slots is pretty simple:

```js
Vue.component('my-wrapper', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div class="box left">
        <slot name="left"></slot>
      </div>
      <div class="box right">
        <slot name="right"></slot>
      </div>
      <div class="after">
        <slot>
          This is some default content
        </slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  min-height: 20px;
  margin: 4px;
}
.box.left {
  float: left;
}
.box.right {
  float: right;
}
.after {
  clear: both;
}

#app > div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <!-- This on just displays the default content -->
  <my-wrapper></my-wrapper>
  
  <!-- Here, the default content is overwritten -->
  <my-wrapper>
    Hello world!
  </my-wrapper>
  
  <!-- Left slot and overwriting the unnamed slot -->
  <my-wrapper>
    <template slot="left">Some left content</template>
    And overwriting the default
  </my-wrapper>

  <!-- Right slot, but keeping the default content -->
  <my-wrapper>
    <template slot="right">Just right content</template>
  </my-wrapper>
  
  <!-- All combined. We don’t have to use the template element -->
  <my-wrapper>
    <div slot="left">Some logo</div>
    <ul slot="right">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <p>This is some new content</p>
  </my-wrapper>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick example:

```
<template id="my-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="left">
      <slot name="left"></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <slot name="right"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And usage:

```
<template>
  <my-wrapper>
    <card slot="left" :data="card1"></card>
    <card slot="right" :data="card2"></card>
  </my-wrapper>
</template>
```